# LSTM from scratch

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

I already learned the basic model of LSTM, for example, layers, cell state, gates, and so on.

However, I am still slightly confused about how the whole thing is done; I want to simulate LSTM step-by-step by hand calculation, like [Neural Networks from Scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wo5dMEP_BbI&t=856s) by sentex.

Is it possible for me to do it?

If yes, is there any good resource, paper, or demo(someone has already done one) that can be referenced and learned from?

Comment: Have you tried just searching it https://duckduckgo.com/?q=lstm+from+scratch, there are tons of tutorials covering this.